# Indirect Form for perfect modals (past modals)

Tags: modal-verbs, perfect-aspect

Is the question formation correct?

1. Could she have killed her?
2. What could you have possibly eaten?

How about in these?

1. I was wondering if she could have killed her.
2. I was wondering what you could have possibly eaten.

Comment: What research have you done yourself?

Comment: All are perfectly good